# Resizing the imageView in a UITableView

Tags: ios4, uitableview, uiimageview

I Created a grouped table view, and I noticed that placing an image in the imageView results in an image that is too large. It overlaps the rounded borders of the cell, which is horrible. I tried looking for a way to resize it, but I found many answers that didn't quite satisfy me. How would you do this? Which is the simplest way to go? The solutions I found where strangely complicated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other solutions didn't satisfy me. The only good solution I found is [this](http://atastypixel.com/blog/easy-rounded-corners-on-uitableviewcell-image-view/). You can resize the UIImage which is passed to the UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is doing in Interface Builder. Select your `UIImegeView` and go to the Inspector 1 view, yo can see View/Mode here choose `ScaleAspectFit` or `ScaleToFill`.

Else do it by code:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

or

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

Comment: Sorry, I understand now my message was absolutely unclear. By imageView I meant the UIImageView which is possible to set in a UITableViewCell in a UITableView. If a place inside it an image, it results to large, I would like to resize that image/view. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I made a mistake. First add you image to the tableview cell:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

then set the content mode:

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

or

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```